# Does user encoding of uploaded files matter and how to configure it?

Tags: django, django-file-upload

I'm making a site on Django. The functionality is as follows - users can download pdf files for processing (converting to different formats, extracting text, etc.).

This is how I receive a file from a user and process it -

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    text = services.extract_text_from_pdf(request.FILES.get('file'))
```

I had the following question - what if users will download files in different encodings? Does their encoding matter or do they all end up being utf-8?

I read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/unicode/#files) from the Django documentation.
But I didn't quite understand how to configure file encoding.

Comment: Are the users uploading PDF files? PDFs are _binary files_. Talking about text encodings isn't meaningful. Any "text" represented in the PDF file is stored per the PDF spec, not with an arbitrary user-selected encoding

Comment: @Brian61354270, Thank you very much! Can this rule also be applied to .docx, .txt files?